# pm2 not start apps on server with Process config loading failed []

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, pm2

I cant start PM2 on DigitalOcean (CentOS7)

```
[PM2] Process config loading failed []
```

Full command ..

```
bash-4.3# pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production
[PM2][WARN] You are starting -1 processes in fork_mode without load balancing. To enable it remove -x option.
[PM2][WARN] Applications api not running, starting...
[PM2] Process config loading failed []
┌──────────┬────┬──────┬─────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬─────┬──────────┐
│ App name │ id │ mode │ pid │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem │ watching │
└──────────┴────┴──────┴─────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴─────┴──────────┘
 Use `pm2 show <id|
```

My ecosystem is ..

```
const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';                                                                                       

if (nodeEnv === 'development') {                                                                                                             
  require('dotenv').config();                                                                                                                
}                                                                                                                                            

const maxMemory = process.env.WEB_MEMORY || 80;                                                                                              

const base = {                                                                                                                               
  source_map_support: true,                                                                                                                  
  node_args: [                                                                                                                               
    '--optimize_for_size',                                                                                                                   
    '--max_old_space_size=400',                                                                                                              
    '--gc_interval=100',                                                                                                                     
  ],                                                                                                                                         
  instances: process.env.WEB_CONCURRENCY || -1,                                                                                              
  exec_mode: 'fork',                                                                                                                         
  max_memory_restart: `${maxMemory}M`,                                                                                                       
};                                                                                                                                           

module.exports = {                                                                                                                           
  apps: [                                                                                                                                    
    Object.assign({}, {                                                                                                                      
      name: 'api',                                                                                                                           
      script: 'api/index.js',                                                                                                                
      env: {                                                                                                                                 
        NODE_ENV: nodeEnv,                                                                                                                   
        PORT: process.env.PORT || 3000,                                                                                                      
        API_MONGO_URL: process.env.API_MONGO_URL || 'mongodb://localhost',                                                          
        JWT_SECRET: process.env.JWT_SECRET || 'AA',                                                                      
        SALT_WORK_FACTOR: process.env.SALT_WORK_FACTOR || 8,                                                                                 
      },                                                                                                                                     
      env_production: {                                                                                                                      
        NODE_ENV: "production",                                                                                                              
        API_MONGO_URL: `mongodb://${process.env.MONGODB_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR}:${process.env.MONGODB_PORT_27017_TCP_PORT}/swarmbot`,           
      },                                                                                                                                     
    }, base),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  ],                                                                                                                                         
};
```

And nothing on logs..

```
bash-4.3# pm2 logs
[TAILING] Tailing last 15 lines for [all] processes (change the value with --lines option)
/root/.pm2/pm2.log last 15 lines:
PM2        | 2017-06-22 02:45:54: ===============================================================================
PM2        | 2017-06-22 02:45:54: --- New PM2 Daemon started ----------------------------------------------------
PM2        | 2017-06-22 02:45:54: Time                 : Thu Jun 22 2017 02:45:54 GMT+0000 (UTC)
PM2        | 2017-06-22 02:45:54: PM2 version          : 2.5.0
PM2        | 2017-06-22 02:45:54: Node.js version      : 7.10.0
PM2        | 2017-06-22 02:45:54: Current arch         : x64
PM2        | 2017-06-22 02:45:54: PM2 home             : /root/.pm2
PM2        | 2017-06-22 02:45:54: PM2 PID file         : /root/.pm2/pm2.pid
PM2        | 2017-06-22 02:45:54: RPC socket file      : /root/.pm2/rpc.sock
PM2        | 2017-06-22 02:45:54: BUS socket file      : /root/.pm2/pub.sock
PM2        | 2017-06-22 02:45:54: Application log path : /root/.pm2/logs
PM2        | 2017-06-22 02:45:54: Process dump file    : /root/.pm2/dump.pm2
PM2        | 2017-06-22 02:45:54: Concurrent actions   : 2
PM2        | 2017-06-22 02:45:54: SIGTERM timeout      : 1600
PM2        | 2017-06-22 02:45:54: ===============================================================================

[STREAMING] Now streaming realtime logs for [all] processes
```